# Jersey Asynchronous Services Throws Error while closing the output stream in order to commit response

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have just tried the [sample resource](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html) explaining the asynchronous response getting resumed by different thread which did not start the resource method.

[Environment used:tomcat 7, jersey 2.3]
when making post request right after get request as in the example. I have following issues:

1) Iam getting NPE while server runtime writing the response as "error while closing output stream in order to cimmit response. ( <-- some times the post request completes with out any exception)

```
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:462)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.endRequest(InternalOutputBuffer.java:159)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:749)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:173)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.finish(Response.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:293)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:108)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.close(CommittingOutputStream.java:275)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.close(OutboundMessageContext.java:835)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse.close(ContainerResponse.java:411)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:625)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:357)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder$3.run(ServerRuntime.java:759)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:295)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder.resume(ServerRuntime.java:797)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder.resume(ServerRuntime.java:754)
```

2) My client request (method type - GET), was NOT getting the asynchronous response written by the post method call. I don't get any exceptions.

### code I tried:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HEAD;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.container.Suspended;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ManagedAsync;

@Path("/messages/next")
public class MessagingResource {
    private static final BlockingQueue<AsyncResponse> suspended =
        new ArrayBlockingQueue<AsyncResponse>(5, Boolean.TRUE);

@GET
@ManagedAsync
public void readMessage(@Suspended AsyncResponse ar) throws InterruptedException {
    echo(" readMessage: before put");
    synchronized (MessagingResource.class) {
        echo(" readMessage: before put, count :"+suspended.size());
        suspended.put(ar);
        echo(" readMessage: after put, count :"+suspended.size());
    }
    echo(" readMessage: after put");
}

@POST
@ManagedAsync
public String postMessage() throws InterruptedException {

    AsyncResponse ar = null; 
    echo(" postMessage: before take, resume");
    synchronized (MessagingResource.class) {
        echo(" postMessage: before put, count :"+suspended.size());
        ar = suspended.take();
        echo(" postMessage: after put, count :"+suspended.size());
    }
    String message = " TEST TEST";
    ar.resume(message ); // resumes the processing of one GET request
    echo(" postMessage: after take , resume");
    return "Message sent";
}

private void echo(String string) {
    String dtStr = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG).format(new Date());
    System.out.println( dtStr + " : " +string );
}
```

Comment: please advise a working example for jaxrs2.0 asynchronous server response concept using @suspended.